# custom component inside form

Tags: apex, visualforce-component, case-object, form

i am try to make custom "NEW CASE" page and have problem:
I'am receive this message when try to post Case:
Unknown property 'CaseSSCFixComponentController.Support_Service_Contract'

Part of page:

```
<apex:page standardcontroller="Case" tabStyle="Case">
<apex:messages />
<apex:sectionheader title="{!$ObjectType.Case.label} Create" subtitle="{!IF(ISNULL(Case.CaseNumber), 'New Case',Case.CaseNumber)}"/>
<apex:form >
    <apex:pageblock mode="new" title="{!$ObjectType.Case.label} Create">
        <apex:pageblockbuttons >
            <apex:commandbutton value="Save" action="{!Save}"/>
            <apex:commandbutton value="Cancel" action="{!Cancel}"/>
        </apex:pageblockbuttons>
        <apex:inputfield value="{!Case.Subject}" required="true"/>
        <apex:inputfield value="{!Case.Description}" required="true"/>
        ...
        <c:CaseSSCFixComponent />
        <apex:inputfield value="{!Case.ContactId}" required="true"/>
    </apex:pageblock>
</apex:form>
```

component:

```
<apex:component controller="CaseSSCFixComponentController" allowDML="true" >
<apex:componentBody >
            <apex:selectList value="{!Support_Service_Contract}" id="Support_Service_Contract__c" multiselect="false" size="1">
                <apex:selectOptions value="{!items}"/>
            </apex:selectList>
</apex:componentBody>
```

controller:

```
public with sharing class CaseSSCFixComponentController {

String[] Support_Service_Contract = new String[]{};

    public List<SelectOption> getItems() {
        List<SelectOption> options = new List<SelectOption>();
        Profile uProfile = [SELECT Id, Name FROM Profile WHERE Id=:userinfo.getProfileId() LIMIT 1];
        if (uProfile.Name != 'Customer Community Login Profile'){

        }
        else{
            User UserInformation = [SELECT Contactid, AccountId FROM User WHERE id=:userinfo.getUserId() LIMIT 1];
            LIST<Support_service_Contract__c> SSC = [SELECT Name, id FROM Support_Service_Contract__c WHERE Status_Active__c = TRUE limit 5 ];
            if (SSC.size() > 0){
                for (Support_service_Contract__c SSCItem : SSC){
                    options.add(new SelectOption(SSCItem.Id, SSCItem.Name));
                }
            }
        }
        return options;
    }

    public String[] getSupport_Service_Contract() {
        return Support_Service_Contract;
    }

    public void setSupport_Service_Contract(String[] Support_Service_Contract) {
        this.Support_Service_Contract = Support_Service_Contract;
    }
```

}

I need help please, what's wrong?
My goal:
I'm try to replace annoying "lookup field(with filter)" to "selector" in case form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taken from SFDC documentation for [apex:selectedList](http://www.salesforce.com/docs/developer/pages/Content/pages_compref_selectList.htm) about the `value` parameter :

> A merge field that references the controller class variable that is
>   associated with this selectList. For example, if the name of the
>   associated variable in the controller class is myListSelections, use
>   value="{!myListSelections}" to reference the variable. If multiselect
>   is true, the value attribute must be of type String[] or a List of
>   strings. Otherwise, it must be of type String.

Your option for multi-select is false, so it's expecting a string and not an array of strings

Comment: thank you, i've just replace String[] to String in controller